# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, innertext

---

actually i have two error and i have no idea where the first one comes from. I included jQuery v.2.1.3 from "code.jquery.com" and Chrome shows me this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined**

The secound Error is from myself i guess.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mydiv" style="height:500px; width:500px; margin:50px auto; background-color:#ddd;">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $.scrollbar = function(options){
                var opts = $.extend($.scrollbar.defaults, options);
            };

            $.scrollbar.defaults = {
                background: "yellow"
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $(function(){
            $('.mydiv').scrollbar();
            //Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Could someone help me? im at the end of my google skills and soon to give up.

Comment: i do not see `innerText` in your code?

Comment: @void It comes from the jQuery include somewhere. The name of the file is `det.js`.

Comment: And what is `scrollbar`?

Comment: That's my function i want to call

Comment: The plugin is empty, i was trying to create one for tests but i didn't even reach the function.

Comment: And what browser are you testing this is?

Comment: Chrome 40.0 and IE11

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what innerText has to do with the error, you should just be getting the error *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*

The way you are making the plug-in is wrong. This is a basic plug-in structure. Notice the use of `fn`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollbar = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend($.fn.scrollbar.defaults, options);
    
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", opts.background);
    });
    
  };

  $.fn.scrollbar.defaults = {
    background: "yellow"
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('.mydiv').scrollbar();
  $('.myOtherDiv').scrollbar({ "background":"red"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">XXXXXXXXXX</div>
<div class="myOtherDiv">XXXXXXXXXX</div>
```

Comment: All right i got it, but for what does the `fn` stand for in `$.fn.scrollbar` ?